# Android - GridView height to max height

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a GridView inside a scrollview and the GridView has 4 images loaded into it (via an ImageAdapter).  My issue is I can get 3 of the images to show but the 4th doesn't.  After further investigation, I've found that the height of the gridview is only the height of the row, so if I set the gridview height in xml to 700dp, then it shows up.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, I've set the background of the GridView to HotPink to illustrate where the GridView is.

Here's the XML for the main_menu:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llLayoutContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    

    <!-- <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llMiddle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"> -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLeft"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"> 
            <ScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/svMenu"
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
            </ScrollView>           
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llRight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_right"
            android:padding="0dp"> 
        </LinearLayout>
    <!-- </LinearLayout> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout "llLeft" is the layout where the menu items get loaded (inside the ScrollView).  layout_left is only a shape which draws the dark outline around the greenish background.

Here's the main_menu_header.xml which contains the GridView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvDashboardHeader"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:text="Dashboard Main Menu"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             style="@style/TextShadow"
             android:paddingTop="5dp"
             android:gravity="left"
             android:background="@drawable/menu_item_bg"        
            />
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gvMenuItems"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="110dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"    
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"    
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"    
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:background="@color/HotPink"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's how I populate the GridView:

```
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.svMenu);
        LayoutInflater liInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)liInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_header, sv, false);
        sv.addView(vg);

        //Setup the Main Menu items on the left side.
        GridView gvMenuItems = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMenuItems);    
        gvMenuItems.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

ImageAdapter class:

ImageAdapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;    

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;    
    }    

    public int getCount() {        
        return mThumbIds.length;    
    }    

    public Object getItem(int position) {        
        return null;    
    }    

    public long getItemId(int position) {        
        return 0;    
    }    

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter    
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {        

        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes            
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getLayoutParams().width, 125)); //new GridView.LayoutParams(400, 125));             
            //imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
            imageView.setMaxHeight(50);
            imageView.setMaxWidth(50);
            //imageView.setPadding(30, 0, 0, 0);
            //imageView.setPadding(40, 30, 20, 30);

            } else {            
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;        
            }        

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }    

    // references to our images    
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.open_folder, 
            R.drawable.paper_pen,
            R.drawable.person
    };
}
```

I thought the gridview property of android:layout_height="match_parent" would work but it's not.  Any ideas as to how I can get the GridView to take up the whole left side, inside the scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that `scrollview` is giving you problem.

Why do u need `scrollview` for?

Grid View will handle the scrolling. It is kind of redundant.So please remove it and add inflated view directly to `llLeft` directly. That shall solve the problem.

---

In fact, it would be more elegant just to use xml to solve your UI problem. Use `<include>` tag in your `main_menu.xml`. Here is how

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llLayoutContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >    

<!-- <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llMiddle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLeft"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"> 
        <include
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/main_menu_header" />           
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llRight"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_right"
        android:padding="0dp"> 
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- </LinearLayout> -->
```

Comment: You're right...scrollview is redundant....after making the changes to the xml, do I just set the gridview adapter to the ImageAdapter?  I tried this but nothing is appearing, I'm guessing because the ImageAdapter doesn't inflate the view but not too sure.  My brain is a little trashed ATM.  How do I inflate the view directly?

Comment: You just need to use the last two lines of code in your question if you are following xml I suggested. 

//Setup the Main Menu items on the left side.
        GridView gvMenuItems = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMenuItems);    
        gvMenuItems.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

Comment: You can try your old way. Just remove scroll-view . It should work too.

Comment: yeah, I tried to add just the include and then only this:          GridView gvMenuItems = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvMenuItems);    
         gvMenuItems.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  but nothing appears now.  Is it because I don't actually inflate anything in the ImageAdapter class?  I've added it to the above post for a reference.

Comment: Just an FYI, that was the issue....I wasn't inflating the view in the adapter (nor was I doing it in the activity anymore)...now it works.  Thanks again for the help and tips, much appreciated!